# Questions regarding the tag merging/synonym for [ibm-bluemix]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

IBM Bluemix was recently rebranded as the IBM Cloud platform in this recent [official announcement](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/10/bluemix-is-now-ibm-cloud/). We currently have the [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tag that is used on most of the questions for the platform. As with any rebranding, it takes a while for everyone to get accustomed to it. We would like [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) to be the master tag and [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) to be a synonym tag. As I understand it, if someone added the [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tag to a question, it would then be automatically published as [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud). However, **before we make that official request**, I have a few questions:

- If the change is made, how does that affect RSS feeds? If someone is following the [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tag, will the [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) tagged questions be included?
- When you use the SO API to pull tag metrics, how will the tag change affect it? If we begin querying on [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) for metrics, will the results continue to include questions tagged as [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix)?

Comment: I can't answer the RSS feed bullet and for the SO API metrics I don't understand what you use. Is it the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) or [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: This question was answered here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303772/questions-regarding-the-tag-merging-synonym-impact

Comment: Ah, that is nice. Awesome.