# Merging/Renaming/Synonym request for IBM Bluemix-related tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

IBM Bluemix was recently rebranded as the IBM Cloud platform in the following recent official announcement: 
[Bluemix is now IBM Cloud](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/10/bluemix-is-now-ibm-cloud/)

As a Knowledge Manager for IBM Cloud Support, I am requesting some changes to the Bluemix-related tags.

- Create the [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) tag. We currently have the [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tag that is used on most of the questions for the platform. **We would like [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) to be the master tag and [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) to be a synonym tag.** In the end, [ibm-cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud) will show on all past and future questions about the platform. Here's a post in which the [ibm-bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-bluemix) tag exists: [Bluemix Git connect to Git Desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647083/bluemix-git-connect-to-git-desktop)
- Create the [ibm-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-mobile-services) tag. We would like [ibm-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-mobile-services) to be the master tag and [bluemix-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix-mobile-services) to be a synonym tag. Here's a post where the [bluemix-mobile-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix-mobile-services) tag exists: [How to avoid duplicate entries in IBM JSONStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47489647/how-to-avoid-duplicate-entries-in-ibm-jsonstore)
- Create the [ibm-cloud-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud-tools) tag and have the [bluemixtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemixtools) tag be made a synonym of it. Here's a post where the [bluemixtools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemixtools) tag exists: [Bluemix secure gateway client on AIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47431644/bluemix-secure-gateway-client-on-aix)
- Create the [ibm-cloud-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud-plugin) tag and have [bluemix-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix-plugin) be made a synonym of it. Here is a post where the [bluemix-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix-plugin) tag exists: [Can not install IBM-Logging plugin on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781318/can-not-install-ibm-logging-plugin-on-windows)
- Retag the 3 [bluemix-dev-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix-dev-services) tag entries with [devops-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devops-services) and then delete the [bluemix-dev-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix-dev-services) tag.
- Delete the [bluemix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix) tag because it is not being used and it is no longer relevant.
- Delete the [bluemix-appid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bluemix-appid) tag because it is not being used. Instead, [ibm-appid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-appid) is being used.

Thank you in advance! If I need to break up this post into multiple requests to make it easier, please let me know and I'll be happy to do it.

Comment: I thought I had seen this before but your other question was about the concern for [the behavior of the RSS feed and statistics](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359193/questions-regarding-the-tag-merging-synonym-for-ibm-bluemix)

Comment: @rene Exactly! I finally got the answers that I needed before I submitted the requests. Unfortunately, I don't have the 2500 points to do most of it myself.

Comment: Here's the post where I asked my original set of questions, which gave me the information I needed to make my official request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303772/questions-regarding-the-tag-merging-synonym-impact

Comment: Tags can't be created without a question so at a minimum having a link 
 to question where each new tag would fit can help.

Comment: @rene I'll edit the post and add that info. Thanks!

Comment: The re-tagging of [tag:bluemix-dev-services] is complete. That tag will be gone at 03:00 UTC.

Comment: I've added the other posts as requested. Thanks for your help!

Comment: [ibm-cloud-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ibm-cloud-tools) already existed, I have created the other tags for you. Please create excerpts and wiki's for them so those questions asked with them are on-topic. Oh, and ask your marketing team to stop rebranding stuff ...

Comment: @rene If tags get merged, the wikis will just get copied over as they already exist if the target tag has no wiki. ;)

Comment: @animuson Oh, I wasn't sure how that worked, I assumed they stayed behind. Thanks.

Comment: @rene - Hahaha...well, rebranding is out my control. But, the good thing is that we are cleaning up some unused tags here too. :-)

Comment: @William I'm marking this as complete as I think everything should be as requested now. If you can double check though (maybe allow for a little caching) - that'd be great.

Comment: @JonClements Yes. Thank you (!) to everyone involved. I have verified that the tags are changed and look correct.